# org.postfix.master - Service exited with abnormal code: 1

Tags: network

I've googled a lot on this issue, yet still seem to have found nothing that quite matches my situation.

Initially, I saw a lot of this error in main Console, repeating every 10 seconds

```
08/04/2015 19:11:11.102 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (org.postfix.master[1129]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
08/04/2015 19:11:21.198 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (org.postfix.master) Service only ran for 1 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 9 seconds.
```

I have found a lot… a lot.. of tweaks & fixes for this, but combined with this error in `/var/log/mail`

```
postfix/master[***]: fatal: bind fe80::1 port 25: Can't assign requested address
```

I could find nothing except references to Mac OS Server & the `inet_interfaces` structure.

I'm running regular Yosemite on a Mac Pro 3,1 - no server structure at all on here.

From my 'not geeky enough to qualify' perspective, it looks like it's trying to find some kind of IPv6 connection yet failing...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to [Postfix not working on MacOS Yosemite](https://serverfault.com/questions/646284/postfix-not-working-on-macos-yosemite) I managed to find the solution…

I tweaked my hosts file from

```
fe80::1%lo0    localhost
```

to

```
fe80::1%lo0    127.0.0.1
```

& the 9 second respawn has vanished.