# How do I destroy postfix on mac os x

Tags: macos, launchd

I see these two log statements non-stop in my console logs..
[image: postfix error]

I have previously tried to eliminate postfix using this command

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist
```

and

```
sudo launchctl remove /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist
```

But it keeps coming back to life after every reboot.

Do I really need postfix? I am a regular GMail user and I don't need any system apps to send emails.

I tried using the instructions at 
[How can I revert my etc/postfix/main.cf file?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/200564/how-can-i-revert-my-etc-postfix-main-cf-file/200565#200565)
to reset my postfix configuration to the stock version with the hope that it might start working normally but it did not help.

Comment: Did you see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180070/org-postfix-master-service-exited-with-abnormal-code-1 ?

Comment: Tried it. No luck. I have to find out where it logs its problems. Not much in console.

Comment: I just added a root crontab entry to shut it down. :)

Answer (score 1):

`sudo rm /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist`  will prevent postfix from starting at launch and being daemonized (if it has been installed in a usual way). This will effectively prevent postfix from running. However, removal of all files and config is another matter. If you installed using a package manager then that’s the way to remove it. Otherwise you have to search your computer and remove postfix-related files.

The `unload` comando just stops a service from running but, as you have noticed, starts again at boot because the `plist` file is still present.

You probably don’t need postfix on your Mac. It’s mostly for use for sending mail from a server (smtp server)—Gmail, yes, does that for you. You might have installed postfix so PHP can send emails, but for development you could try a faux postfix that logs instead of sends like Mailhog.

Comment: Is this a clarification or rhetorical question?  What ***about*** that command makes it an answer to the OP's question?